# EventStore throws ConcurrencyException when using RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, cqrs, neventstore

My wire up looks like this.

```
return Wireup.Init()
      .UsingRavenPersistence("RavenDB")
      .ConsistentQueries()
      .InitializeStorageEngine()
      .UsingJsonSerialization()
      .Build();
```

When I try to save an event, like this:

```
using (eventStore)
using (var stream = eventStore.CreateStream(myEvent.AggreagateId))
{
    stream.Add(new EventMessage { Body = myEvent });
    stream.CommitChanges(myEvent.Id);
}
```

It throws an `EventStore.ConcurrencyException`

I'm using eventstore 3.0 and RavenDB 2.0

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the stack trace:

```
EventStore.ConcurrencyException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Exception of type 'EventStore.ConcurrencyException' was thrown.
  Source=EventStore.Persistence.RavenPersistence
  StackTrace:
       at EventStore.Persistence.RavenPersistence.RavenPersistenceEngine.Commit(Commit attempt) in c:\Code\public\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Persistence.RavenPersistence\RavenPersistenceEngine.cs:line 135
       at EventStore.OptimisticEventStore.Commit(Commit attempt) in c:\Code\public\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Core\OptimisticEventStore.cs:line 98
       at EventStore.OptimisticEventStream.PersistChanges(Guid commitId) in c:\Code\public\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Core\OptimisticEventStream.cs:line 166
       at EventStore.OptimisticEventStream.CommitChanges(Guid commitId) in c:\Code\public\EventStore\src\proj\EventStore.Core\OptimisticEventStream.cs:line 147
       at TeamHabits.Web.Habit.CreateHabitModule.<>c__DisplayClass6.<.ctor>b__1(Object _) in c:\Users\Emil\Dropbox\Active projects\TeamHabits\Source\TeamHabits.Web\Habit\CreateHabitModule.cs:line 41
       at Nancy.Routing.Route.Invoke(DynamicDictionary parameters)
       at Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteInvoker.Invoke(Route route, DynamicDictionary parameters, NancyContext context)
       at Nancy.Routing.DefaultRequestDispatcher.Dispatch(NancyContext context)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is causing EventStore to throw ConcurrencyException so easily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755348/what-is-causing-eventstore-to-throw-concurrencyexception-so-easily)

Comment: @EmilC please respond - I should really just back up the vote to close. Do you have a stacktrace? Is it different?

Comment: Yes it is different. I'll update with stack trace asap.

Comment: +1 Good stuff. Does this happen consistently? Are you simply triggering a single request or doing anything more interesting?

Comment: Everytime I hit the page using the event store.

Comment: The version of EventStore and RavenDB are not compatible. I think there is a update version comming.